# Compare two series from different dataframes, and where match found replace with third series value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

There is my main dataframe containing some data, and it has the world countries in ISO country code alpha-2 (meaning two letter symbol). Eventually the dataframe will be merged with another which has the world countries in ISO country code alpha-3 (meaning three letter symbol). There is some python package to do the conversion but it should be possible with simple reference csv file to compare and replace manually in dataframes.

Edit: The country codes in two dataframes are NOT in the same order (some missing/no population), that is why I need to iterate and pick out manually each symbol.

I am stuck in the code formulation since i am beginner and cant pin the correct syntax. Keep getting the:
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

I tried to fetch index locations and values, but cant append the new series to original dataframe. I made a simple for loop to test and visualise what i am trying to achieve, see in the code.

```
# notebook magic
%matplotlib inline

# import packages
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas

# import excel data from files
# note: here the countries are in ISO 3166-1 alpha-2
joblist = pd.read_excel('joblist.xlsx', sheet_name='Joblist', header=1).reset_index(drop=True)

# load iso-countries reference file for conversion
countries = pd.read_csv('iso-countries.csv')

# load the world map dataset and remove Antartica and empty countries
# note: here the countries are in ISO 3166-1 alpha-3
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]

# just for testing, iterate and fetch correct value, THIS fetched value should be appended to main dataframe 
for value in world['iso_a3']:
    print('* INPUT VALUE *', value)
    print('* FETCHED VALUE *', countries['alpha-2'].loc[countries['alpha-3'] == value])

# append new iso alpha-2 value to world dataframe
# THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE I AM STUCK IN
world['iso_a2'] = countries['alpha-2'].where(world['iso_a3'] == countries['alpha-3'])
```

From my for loop this is example of what I want to achieve for one country. Iterate through ISO alpha-3 series in "world" dataframe and for each item, search "countries" dataframe and locate the row where that item is located ("UKR"). Then when I get the correct row, copy the alpha-2 value ("UA") to the "world" dataframe.

For loop output example:

- INPUT "COMMON" VALUE * IS: UKR
- FETCHED VALUE * IS: 232    UA
- Name: alpha-2, dtype: object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to turn the `countries` DataFrame into a Series that `Series.replace()` can accept. To do this, set the `alpha-3` column of `countries` as the index; this should return a DataFrame with one index and one column, named `alpha-2`. Pass the `alpha-2` column (which is a pandas series) to `world['iso_a3'].replace()` as follows:

```
world['iso_a2'] = world['iso_a3'].replace(countries.set_index('alpha-3')['alpha-2'])
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, forgot to mention that the order is not the same, that is why i am iterating through the series instead of doing just replace.

Comment: @inxcent, `input_series.replace(dict_or_series)` is specifically designed to handle arbitrary ordering of keys in `input_series`. For each element in `input_series`, the corresponding key in `dict_or_series` is looked up and the resulting value is replaced in. This implicit loop without an explicit `for` loop is the so-called "vectorized" approach that is encouraged for pandas and numpy.

Comment: beautiful! this is exactly what i needed, had no idea there is such a method already in place. At first glance, thought this was only a straight "cut-paste" method. Thank you! This produced the correct result.